# removing stop words after tokenizing string in java

Tags: java, tokenize, stop-words

I want to remove stop word after tokenizing string. I have external file .txt and read it then compare it to the tokenized string. if the tokenized word is equal with the stop word, then remove it.

here is the code for tokenizing

```
try{
            while ((msg =readBufferData.readLine()) != null) {
                int numberOfTokens;

                System.out.println("Before: "+msg);
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(msg);

                numberOfTokens = tokens.countTokens();
                System.out.println("Tokens: "+numberOfTokens);

                System.out.print("After : ");
                while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    msg = tokens.nextToken();
                    String msgLower = msg.toLowerCase();
                    String punctuationremove = punctuationRemover(msgLower);  
          //          buffWriter.write(punctuationremove+" "); --> write into file .txt
                    System.out.print(punctuationremove+" ");
                    removingStopWord(punctuationremove, readStopWordsFile());
                    numberOfTotalTokens++;   
                }
           //     buffWriter.newLine(); make a new line after tokening new message
                System.out.println("\n");
                numberOfMessages++;
            }
        // write close    buffWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Total Tokens: "+numberOfTotalTokens);
            System.out.println("Total Messages: "+numberOfMessages);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Then I have a code for reading the stop word file

```
public static Set<String> readStopWordsFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String fileStopWords = "\\stopWords.txt";

    Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    FileReader readFileStopWord = new FileReader(fileStopWords);
    BufferedReader stopWordsFile = new BufferedReader(readFileStopWord);

    String line;

    while((line = stopWordsFile.readLine())!=null){
        line = line.trim();
        stopWords.add(line);
    }
    stopWordsFile.close();
    return stopWords;
}
```

How can I compare the token with the set of stop word and delete the token that same with the stop word. Can you help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read the stop words first and then check whether your token is a stopword.

```
Set<String> stopWords = readStopWordsFile();

  // some file reading logic
  while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
       msg = tokens.nextToken();
       if(stopWords.contains(msg)){
         continue; // skip over a stopword token
       }
  }
```

Comment: Stil can not removing the stop word, thank you for the answer by the way

Comment: @RickyKristianButar-butar what does that mean?

Comment: it gives the same output as before. it doesn't removing the stop word

Comment: @RickyKristianButar-butar can you please tell me what `msg` looks like and what `stopWords` contains? Otherwise my only advise for you would be to use a debugger.

Comment: msg is the output after tokenizing the string ex: my name is ricky, ouput: my | name | is | ricky , same as splitting string into words. The stop word file contain words that not have any information, ex: a, although, are, and, etc. so i need to remove all the stop word in the tokenzing result